# what could I use for the function "reduce" in this code?

Tags: python

```
def factors(numer):    
    return set(reduce(list.__add__, ([i, numer//i] for i in range(1, int(numer**0.5) + 1) if numer % i == 0)))
```

I'm trying to find the different sets of factors for the value "numer" but it gives me an error saying:

```
NameError: name 'reduce' is not defined
```

What could I replace reduce with to make my code work?

Comment: If you are using python 3, reduce can be found in the `functools` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import it in python3:

```
from functools import reduce
```

once you do it will work:

```
In [5]: from functools import reduce

In [6]: factors(10)
Out[6]: {1, 2, 5, 10}
```

You could also just flatten with `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain
def factors(numer):
    return set(chain.from_iterable((i, numer//i) for i in range(1, int(numer**0.5) + 1) if numer % i == 0))
```

Or flatten by adding another loop  over the elements in each tuple:

```
def factors(numer):
    return set((j for i in range(1, int(numer**0.5) + 1) if numer % i == 0 for j in (i, numer//i)))
```

Comment: okay thank you i was having difficulties with that. i appreciate your help

Comment: @dirtydan, no worries, you don't really need reduce in any case